# What does successively pressing the Ctrl key twice do?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

See this short video of what actually shows up on screen when we successively press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key twice:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFZTnNH5nIs

What does it do? Is it a shortcut? Acts as a Hotkey? A easter egg? What exactly does happen?

Now, once it has been activated, every single press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key triggers this action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just the "show mouse" highlight.

Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed.

[image]

Comment: Oh... I was playing with the settings earlier today, I somehow activated it and forgot about it. Had never seen it earlier so got a bit amused to watch it :-)